# CXF for Eclipse 3.5

Tags: eclipse, web-services, cxf, eclipse-3.6, eclipse-3.5

I've Eclipse 3.5.2 and I've a web service, under Windows-> Preferences I can't see CXF, I know it's available in Eclipse 3.6 but is there any way to make it available in Eclipse 3.5? Perhaps by downloading the CXF jars or something? My goal is to generate WSDL file from my web service interface.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using eclipse indigo. so I'm not sure if this'll work for you.
If you go to Help > Install New Software. Look for the The Eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP) software repository
I'm using Eclipse Indigo so its > http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/indigo

Now it'll list different "Eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP)" Versions, Select the latest one and you should see CXF Web Services under it. I'll just install the entire platform. you can also install the platform sdk if you like. See the image below for more info.

[Install software http://www.greenkode.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/6-30-2012-12-58-24-PM.jpg](http://www.greenkode.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/6-30-2012-12-58-24-PM.jpg)